# Add a local swift package in swift project in Xcode 13

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, xcode13

I want to add a swift package in my project. It appear in packages folder (by a drag n drop) but my project doesn't see it with "import myPackage", I've no such module error

Answer (score 5):

**1)** Go to you project target -> general -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded content
**2)** add package with + button. ( I only added testFramework on picture below just for example)

[image: this image]

Comment: After this manipulation, my package (it's mine) appear only in the folder but not where you draw the circle

Comment: You need to add it there by clicking the + button and chosing the package from selection

Answer (score 1):

Use `.package(path:)` description in `Package.swift`.

You can add a dependency to a package located at the given path. And you can edit the package when debugging.

As `PackageDescription` mentioned this description:

*The Swift Package Manager uses the package dependency as-is and does not perform any source control access. Local package dependencies are especially useful during the development of a new package or when working on multiple tightly coupled packages.*